# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT ... ORDER BY without a temporary table or filesort

Tags: mysql, database

I have a query running on a table with half a million rows.  I have a composite index called wafer_name_date on the columns (wafer_name, date).  By adding the index, this query now takes .06 seconds, but still reports using a temporary table and filesort.  Is there any way to avoid this?  thanks!

```
EXPLAIN SELECT DISTINCT wafer_name FROM flash ORDER BY date\G 
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: flash
         type: range
possible_keys: NULL
          key: wafer_name_date
      key_len: 767
          ref: NULL
         rows: 4308
        Extra: Using index for group-by; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

Comment: What is your table structure? (the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table`)

Answer (score 2):

Your query is a bit awkward, because "date" is not included in the result set.  Yet, you are ordering by date.  I would expect something like:

```
select wafer_name, min(date)
from flash
group by wafe_name
order by min(date)
```

As the explain says, the execution plan using the index for the grouping (distinct) values.  This produces a single value for wafer_name and an arbitrary value for date.  It is pulling the arbitrary date from the index (rather than looking it up on the corresponding page).

However, it then needs to sort the results by date.  It can't use the index you defined, because this is by wafer_name first, and you only have one date per wafer_name.  So it saves out the data and does a sort.

I can't think of a way around this.